# Create a list of distinct values from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Right now I have code that gets the distinct value from running SQL code on a table. I now use a stored proc to fill my Gridview instead of pulling from a table and can't do select distinct on a table since it's not there. I wanted to know if someone could point me in the right direction to create my list by using the values of a gridview.

Here is the current code I want to switch.

```
connection = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());

string strSQL = string.Empty;
switch (strColumnName)
{
    case "SiteID":
        strSQL = @"SELECT distinct SiteID, SiteID FROM Sites ";
        break;
    case "OrderDate":
        strSQL = @"SELECT distinct OrderDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), OrderDate, 106) AS [OrderDate] FROM Sites ";
        break;
}

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = strSQL;
command.Connection = connection;

command.Connection.Open();

SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

IList<FilterValueSet> filterValueList = new List<FilterValueSet>();

while (dataReader.Read())
{
    filterValueList.Add(new FilterValueSet
    {
        Id = dataReader[0].ToString(),
        Value = dataReader[1].ToString()
    });
}
connection.Close();

return filterValueList.ToArray<FilterValueSet>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq [Distinct() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to filter the results like

```
return filterValueList.Distinct(equalityComparer).ToArray();
```

You need to provide an [equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your `FilterValueSet` class, something in this way:

```
class MyEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<FilterValueSet>
{
  public override int GetHashCode(FilterValueSet obj) 
  {
    return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
  }
  public override bool Equals(T x, T y)
  {
    return x.Id.Equals(y.Id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I havn't used the linq distinct() method before or a quality compare so I'll need to read into them. I'll let you know how it works out.